# How to make a connection between two shapes dynamically, means position and all will be passed dynamically in Kendo diagram

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a `kendo` diagram, in that one shape is already there, I have to add the next shapes, and after that next should be added to the Parent Shape or child Shape based on the condition specified dynamically and shape type will also be specified dynamically.

I have kept a button after clicking on that button, the shape is coming but not dynamically.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="createBtn">Create Shape</button>
<div id="diagram"></div>
<script>
    $("#createBtn").on("click", function(){
      //var count=kendo.dataviz.diagram.Shape().count();
      //alert(count);
      var diagram = $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram();
      var shape = new kendo.dataviz.diagram.Shape({
            type: "circle",
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            stroke: {
                width: 1,
                color: "#red"
            },
            fill: "#e8eff7",
            editable: true
        });

      var diagram = $("#diagram").getKendoDiagram();
      diagram.addShape(shape);
      diagram.bringIntoView(diagram.shapes);
    });

    var Shape = kendo.dataviz.diagram.Shape;
    $("#diagram").kendoDiagram();
    var diagram = $("#diagram").data("kendoDiagram");

    var shape = new Shape({x: 500, y: 100, fill: "red"});
    diagram.addShape(shape);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If i pass the shape type and shape location to which it should get bind. It should give an Shape Connected with that specified location.

Answer (score 0):

Create the shape, then connect it.

```
// Connect new shape to last added shape
var diagram = … ;

var count = diagram.shapes.length;    
var lastAddedShape = diagram.shapes[count-1];

var shape = …;

diagram.addShape(shape);
diagram.connect(lastAddedShape, shape);
```